# Function on Click doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, onclick, jquery-click-event

I have to use dynamically created images for my projekt. I do this with jQuery:

```
var img = $('<img />').attr({ 'id': i, 'src': e.files[i].thumbnails["200x200"], 'alt':e.files[i].name, 'class': 'photo'}).appendTo($('#img'));
```

But I can't run a function if the image is clicked. I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".photo").click(function(){
        alert('Works!');    
    });
};
```

and onClick:

```
var img = $('<img />').attr({ 'id': i, 'src': e.files[i].thumbnails["200x200"], 'alt':e.files[i].name, 'class': 'photo', 'onClick': 'test();' }).appendTo($('#img'));
```

[...]

```
function test(){
   alert('Works!');
}
```

But both ways aren't working...
What did I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you need to use on() and delegate on the closest static parent element for dynamically added elements

```
    $(document).on('click','.photo',function(){
        alert('Works!');    
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
$(".photo").click(function(){
    alert('Works!');    
});
```

it is only binding it to the elements in the dom, so once you add dynamic html, it doesn't bind that even to that html. In that case if you use

```
$(document).on('click','.photo',function(){
  alert('Works');
});
```

This code would bind the click event to every element in html even if it is added dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the event handler when creating the image?

```
var img = $('<img>')
            .attr({
                id: i,
                src: e.files[i].thumbnails["200x200"],
                alt: e.files[i].name,
                // keep 'class' for jshint 
                'class': 'photo'
            })
            .click(function () {
                alert('Works!');
            })
            // you can leave out $('#img') and just write:
            .appendTo('#img');
```

of course you should define that click handler function only **once**:

```
function clickHandler() { // do stuff }
```

and add it like `.click(clickHandler)` in the example above.